# Retrieving Values from firebase database, then displaying it as a message from someone who will be receiving it

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

This is the class where I want to retrieve the values in the database

```
public class EmergencyAlertActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar mChatToolbar; //used
private String mChatUser;  //used
private String mthumb_image;
private String userName;
private String mCurrentUserId;
private TextView mUserStatus;
private EditText mChatMessageView;
private String emerg_message;
private String open_location;

private CircleImageView mProfileImage;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private ImageButton mChatAddBtn;
private TextView view_location;

private DatabaseReference mRootRef;
// Storage Firebase
private StorageReference mImageStorage;
private static final int GALLERY_PICK = 1;

private RecyclerView mMessagesList;
private SwipeRefreshLayout mRefreshLayout;

private ArrayList<String> arrayList_Message = new ArrayList<String>();

private AlertAdapter mAdapter;

private static final int TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD = 10;
private int mCurrentPage = 1;
private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_emergency_alert);
    mChatMessageView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chat_message_view);
    mChatAddBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.chat_add_btn);

    mChatToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.chat_app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(mChatToolbar);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

    //for Custom Action bar
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View customBar = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_custom_bar,null);

    actionBar.setCustomView(customBar);

    //getting intent Data
    gettingIntentData();

    // initializing user view
    intCustomBarViewAndSetData();


    mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mCurrentUserId =  mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();




    //------- IMAGE STORAGE ---------
    mImageStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    mRootRef.child("Emergency_Chat").child(mCurrentUserId).child(mChatUser).child("seen").setValue(true);

    LoadMessages();

    //getting information about user online or offline and thumb image
    mRootRef.child("Users").child(mChatUser).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String thumb_image = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();
            Picasso.with(EmergencyAlertActivity.this).load(thumb_image).placeholder(R.drawable.my_profile).into(mProfileImage);

            String lastSeen = dataSnapshot.child("online").getValue().toString();

            if(lastSeen.equals("true")){
                mUserStatus.setText("Online");
            }
            else{

                //converting string into long
                Long lastTime = Long.parseLong(lastSeen);

                // creating an instance of GetTimeAgo class
                GetTimeAgo getTimeAgo = new GetTimeAgo();
                String lastSeenTime = GetTimeAgo.getTimeAgo(lastTime,getApplicationContext());
                mUserStatus.setText(lastSeenTime);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    //for creating chat object
    mRootRef.child("Emergency_Chat").child(mCurrentUserId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(!dataSnapshot.hasChild(mChatUser)){

                Map chatAddMap = new HashMap();
                chatAddMap.put("seen",false);
                chatAddMap.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

                Map chatUserMap = new HashMap();
                chatUserMap.put("Emergency_Chat/"+mCurrentUserId+"/"+mChatUser, chatAddMap);
                chatUserMap.put("Emergency_Chat/"+mChatUser+"/"+mCurrentUserId, chatAddMap);

                mRootRef.updateChildren(chatUserMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

                        if(databaseError!= null){
                            Toast.makeText(EmergencyAlertActivity.this, "Error: "+databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    // Retrieving the chat messages into recyclerview
    LoadMessages();
    mRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {

            mCurrentPage++;

            //onRefresh remove the current messages from arraylist and load new messages
            arrayList_Message.clear();

            // Load message
            LoadMessages();
        }
    });


}
// Load all messages from database into recyclerView
private void LoadMessages() {

    DatabaseReference messageRef = mRootRef.child("Emergency_Messages").child(mCurrentUserId).child(mChatUser);

    //Query to load message per page i.e. 10
    /*
       per page load 10 message and onRefresh mCurrentpage is increment by 1
       page 1 => load 10 messages (mCurrentPage = 1 then 1*10 =10)
       page 2 => load 20 messages (mCurrentPage = 2 then 2*10 =20) and so on
     */

    Query messageQuery = messageRef.limitToLast(mCurrentPage * TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD);

    messageQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            emerg_message = dataSnapshot.child("userName").getValue().toString();
            open_location = dataSnapshot.child("open_location").getValue().toString();

            arrayList_Message.add(emerg_message+ "\n"+"\n"+open_location);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            mMessagesList.scrollToPosition(arrayList_Message.size()-1);

            //when data load completely set refreshing
            mRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void intCustomBarViewAndSetData() {
    TextView mTitleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_bar_title);
    mUserStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_bar_seen);
    mProfileImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.custom_bar_image);
    mMessagesList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.messages_list);

    mMessagesList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.message_swipe_layout);
    mMessagesList.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mAdapter = new AlertAdapter(EmergencyAlertActivity.this, arrayList_Message);
    mMessagesList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    //showing name on toolbar
    mTitleView.setText(userName);
    mTitleView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent profileIntent = new Intent(EmergencyAlertActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
            profileIntent.putExtra("user_id", mChatUser);
            startActivity(profileIntent);
        }
    });




}

private void gettingIntentData() {
    Intent intent =getIntent();
    userName = intent.getStringExtra("Username");
    mChatUser = intent.getStringExtra("user_id");


}
```

}

this is the adapter class

```
  public class AlertAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AlertAdapter.MyAlertViewHolder>{


private ArrayList<String> arrayListMessage= new ArrayList<String>();
private Context mcontext;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;
private String from_user;
private String emerg_message;
private String emerg_location;
private String message_type;

public AlertAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> arrayListMessages){
    this.arrayListMessage = arrayListMessages;
    mcontext = context;
}
@Override
public AlertAdapter.MyAlertViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_single_layout, parent,false);

    return new AlertAdapter.MyAlertViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final AlertAdapter.MyAlertViewHolder holder, int position) {

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    final String mCurrentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

   final  String userName = String.valueOf(arrayListMessage.get(position));



    mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(from_user);
    mUserDatabase.child("Emergency_Messages").child("from").child(mCurrentUser).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             from_user = dataSnapshot.child("from").getValue().toString();
             emerg_message = dataSnapshot.child("userName").getValue().toString();
             emerg_location = dataSnapshot.child("open_location").getValue().toString();

            if (mCurrentUser != from_user){

                holder.textViewMessage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_message_bd_white);
                holder.textViewMessage.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                holder.textViewMessage.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

            } else{
                holder.textViewMessage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_message_bg_primary);
                holder.textViewMessage.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                holder.textViewMessage.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            holder.textViewMessage.setText(emerg_message + "\n"+"\n"+emerg_location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    if(message_type.equals("text")) {

        holder.textViewMessage.setText(emerg_message);
        holder.messageImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


    } else {

        holder.textViewMessage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Picasso.with(holder.UserProfile.getContext()).load(emerg_message)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.my_profile).into(holder.messageImage);

    }



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayListMessage.size();
}

class MyAlertViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView textViewMessage;
    CircleImageView UserProfile;
    ImageView messageImage;

    public MyAlertViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textViewMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
        UserProfile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_profile_layout);
        messageImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_image_layout);
    }


}
```

}

this is the supporting class

```
public class Alerts {
String userName,open_location ,latitude, longitude,type,from;
long time;
boolean seen;

public Alerts(){
    // for datashnap shot
}
public Alerts(String userName,String open_location,String latitude,String longitude, String type, long time, boolean seen, String from) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.open_location = open_location;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.type = type;
    this.time = time;
    this.seen = seen;
    this.from=from;
}

public String getFrom() {
    return from;
}

public void setFrom(String from) {
    this.from = from;
}
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getOpen_location() {
    return open_location;
}

public void setOpen_location(String open_location) {
    this.open_location = open_location;
}
public String getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
    this.latitude= latitude;
}
public String getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
    this.longitude= longitude;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public long getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(long time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public boolean isSeen() {
    return seen;
}

public void setSeen(boolean seen) {
    this.seen = seen;
}
```

}

when i try to run the app and open the class that is going to retrieve information in my database i get this error:

```
01-05 09:54:48.479 29178-29178/? E/Zygote: no v2
01-05 09:54:48.489 29178-29178/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable 
 seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
01-05 10:01:23.395 29178-29178/com.rescuex_za.rescuex E/ViewRootImpl: 
sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
01-05 10:01:27.218 29178-29178/com.rescuex_za.rescuex E/ViewRootImpl: 
sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
01-05 10:01:27.689 29178-29178/com.rescuex_za.rescuex E/AndroidRuntime:
```

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: 
    com.rescuex_za.rescuex, PID: 29178

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in 
child()
                                                                        at 
 com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at 
 com.rescuex_za.rescuex.AlertAdapter.onBindViewHolder(AlertAdapter.java:63)
                                                                        at 
 com.rescuex_za.rescuex.AlertAdapter.onBindViewHolder(AlertAdapter.java:29)
                                                                        at 

  android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.
 onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6482)
                                                                        at 
 android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.
 bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6515)
                                                                        at 
 android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.
 tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5458)
                                                                        at 
  android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.
 tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5724)
                                                                        at 
 android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.
 getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
                                                                        at 
 android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.
 getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
                                                                        at 

 android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.
 next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
                                                                        at 
 android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
                                                                        at 
 android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
  .fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
                                                                        at 
 android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
 .onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
                                                                        at 
 android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
 .dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
                                                                        at 
  android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  .dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3410)
                                                                        at 
 android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3962)
                                                                        at 
 android.view.View.layout(View.java:16075)
                                                                        at 
 android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5300)
                                                                        at 
 android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:610)
                                                                        at 
 android.view.View.layout(View.java:16075)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5300)
                                                                        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1077)
                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16075)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5300)
                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16075)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5300)
                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16075)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5300)
                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16075)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5300)
                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16075)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5300)
                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16075)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5300)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2119)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1873)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1073)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5988)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Loop
```

I have tried everything I thought would help to retrieve this information and display it the way I want it to be displayed but it keeps on crashing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [null for argument 'pathString'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45087951/null-for-argument-pathstring)

Comment: what would be those duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

This error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()` tells you what the problem is. You are passing into `child()` method an argument chich has the value of `null`.

This means that you need to check all your variable like: `mCurrentUserId`, `mChatUser` and so on for nullity. Make sure all this variables have the correct value.